# ASP Chart format axis label in thousands or millions depending on data

Tags: asp.net

I currently use this to format my axisy labels to display £1,000,000 to £1M

```
<axisy>
<LabelStyle Format="£0,,M" />
```

Is there a way I can also make it format to thousands if the value on the chart drops below 1M?

It must be automatic as I can't predict if the chart will returns values in millions or thousands

Comment: Actually you should have access to chart data then you know their range. Moreover you can access axis resolved limits after it displayed data (there you can assign label format according to resolved limits).

Comment: Hi, yes I appreciate that I could interrogate the data, I was just wondering if I could create a format string that would work in both situations

Comment: Ah ok, AFAIK there is not such formatting string.